# Wercker error 404 during setup environment

Tags: github, msbuild, wercker

I'm trying to configure wercker platform to build my project automatically (.NET MVC). I created wercker.yml file, but when I commit my project to github, wercker produces an error during setup environment

```
GET https://registry.hub.docker.com/v1/repositories/wercker-labs/windows/images returned 404
```

I found some tips, someone changed `box: wercker/ruby` to `box: ruby` and it worked, but nothing works for me.

My wercker.yml file:

```
box: wercker-labs/windows
build:
  steps:
    - wercker-labs/msbuild
```

Comment: Got the same problem with `box: wercker/python`: https://github.com/datacdn/bot/blob/master/wercker.yml!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wercker is now version 2. And v2 don't support boxes at the wercker directory. Both 'box:wercker-labs/windows' and 'box:wercker/ruby' can be found at the wercker directory, but you can't use them any more.

Wercker v2 supports only boxes at the docker hub. 'box:ruby' is the official repositories of the docker hub. Official box can be found at https://hub.docker.com/explore/ . And you can also find custom base images which someone have already created.

There are two ways to solve the problem.

- Find the windows image as you need at the docker hub.
- Register new custom image with the docker hub.

Please see the detail:
http://devcenter.wercker.com/docs/faq/migration-tips-v2.html

Comment: Yes, I found it as well, but forgot to answer. I changed 1 option in settings to work with previous version od wercker and it helped

Comment: I'm glad to help you. And thank you for comment. It's a first time being voted, so I can add this comment now.